# Replace when n or less consecutive values are found

Tags: python, replace

this is perhaps a very simple question

I have a list that looks like this:

```
a=[0,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,5,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,1,1,3,4,1]
```

I am struggling to find a simple python code that replaces when ***n*** or less consecutive **1s** are found to 0s and creates a new list with the new values

So if

```
n = 2
```

b = [0,**0,0**,2,3,2,**0**,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,5,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,**0,0**,3,4,**0**]

if

n = 3

b = [0,**0,0**,2,3,2,**0**,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,5,**0,0,0**,3,2,0,2,**0,0**,3,4,**0**]

I have highlighted the new replaces values in each example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One"-liner, using some [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

a=[0,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,5,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,1,1,3,4,1]

list(
    chain.from_iterable(
        ([0] * len(lst) if x == 1 and len(lst) <= n else lst 
         for x, lst in ((k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a)))
    )
)
# [0,0,0,2,3,2,0,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0, 0,4,5,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,0,0,3,4,0]
```

`groupby` groups the initial list into groups of identical objects. Its output is an iterator of pairs `(k, g)` where `k` is the element that is the grouping key and `g` is an iterator producing the actual elements in the group.

Since you cannot call `len` on an iterator, this listifies the groups and chains the resulting lists except lists of `1` of the appropriate lengthes. Those are replaced by lists of `0` of the same length.

In single steps (using intermediate lists instead of generators):

```
grouped_lists_by_key = [k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a)]
# [(0, [0]), (1, [1, 1]), ...]

grouped_lists = [[0] * len(lst) if x == 1 and len(lst) <= n else lst for x, lst in grouped]
# [[0], [0, 0], [2], [3], ...]

flattened = chain.from_iterable(grouped_lists)
# [0, 0, 0, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: That's great! Many thanks! Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: I added some explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
a=[0,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,5,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,1,1,3,4,1]
n = 3
new_list = list(itertools.chain(*[[0]*len(b) if a == 1 and len(b) <= n else b for a, b in [(c, list(d)) for c, d in itertools.groupby(a)]]))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-oneliner using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
a = [0,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,5,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,1,1,3,4,1]
n = 2
b = []
for k, g in groupby(a):
    l = list(g)
    if k == 1 and len(l) <= n:
        b.extend([0]*len(l))
    else:
        b.extend(l)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def replacer(array, n):
    i, consec = 0, 0
    while i < len(array):
        if array[i] == 1:
            consec += 1
        else:
            if consec >= n:
                for x in range(i-consec, i):
                    array[x] = 0
            consec = 0
        i += 1
    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

Longer than others, but arguably straightforward:

```
a = [0,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,0,3,4,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,5,1,1,1,3,2,0,2,1,1,3,4,1]

def suppress_consecutive_generator(consecutive=2, toreplace=1, replacement=0):
    def gen(l):
        length = len(l)
        i = 0
        while i < length:
            if l[i] != toreplace:
                yield l[i]
                i += 1
                continue
            j = i
            count = 0
            while j < length:
                if l[j] != toreplace:
                    break
                count += 1
                j += 1
            i += count
            if count <= consecutive:
                for _ in range(count):
                    yield replacement
            else:
                for _ in range(count):
                    yield toreplace
    return gen

print(list(suppress_consecutive_generator()(a)))
```